# Android: How to access a ScrollView inside a Fragment which is part of an ViewPagerAdapter for a ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager, position, scrollview

I'm using a ViewPager2 with a ViewPagerAdapter. This adapter includes Fragments. The layout of this Fragment has a ScrollView.

What I want to do is to scroll the ScrollView of the shown Fragment to a certain position after clickling a button in the MainActivity. But I don't know how to get the ScrollView. All I know is how to get the shown item (mPager.getCurrentItem).

**Details**

```
Fragement:
public class ChapterFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPagerAdapter:
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter

MainActivity:
ViewPager2 mPager;
ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
mPager= findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Does anybody can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A highly unsatisfactory answer would be to do the following when your button is clicked:

```
ViewPager2 yourViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
String tag = "f" + yourViewPager.getCurrentItem();
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(frag != null) {
    //find scrollview with 'frag.getView().findViewById...' and scroll to required position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple things u can do there.

1. Implement an interface in activity.
2. implement a following code on OnClick of button.
   make scrollview variable public in Fragment
   if(mPager.getCurrentItem() instanceof ChapterFragment)
   {
   ChapterFragment chapterFragment =
   (ChapterFragment)mPager.getCurrentItem();
   chapterFragment.scrollView.scrollTo(20) //move to specific position

}

Comment: getCurrentItem() returns an int

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Thanks. It works with Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

 ChapterFragment chapterFragment = (ChapterFragment)mPager.getCurrentItem(); does not work because getCurrentItem return an integer and not a reference